# Angular CLI 7 Webpack Bundle Analyzer modules concatenated

Tags: angular, webpack, angular7, angular-cli-v7, webpack-bundle-analyzer

I'm running Webpack Bundle Analyzer for my Angular 7 app and it's producing output like this:

[image]

This is a known caveat when webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin is used per the troubleshooting section [found here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer).  They have a recommendation for Angular CLI < 6.  I've also found suggestions [here](https://twitter.com/olore/status/937523005407813632) which suggests commenting out ModuleConcatenationPlugin, however, it does not identify where it should be commented out.

Do you know how to fix modules concatenated for Angular CLI 7.1.0?  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you've found the answer to your question [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer/issues/236).

In the left sidebar there's a checkbox labeled "Show content of concatenated modules" which is unchecked by default. Check it and you will see a much more detailed breakdown of what is in your main.js file.

Comment: works well for me 